# MNIST saving images from CSV using matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, mnist

In the MNIST dataset, I have the images in the CSV format, each of the 784 columns corresponds to a pixel intensity. I want to save each of these images without looking at them with `imshow`.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i=0
with open('Book1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
for data in csv.reader(csv_file):

    # The rest of columns are pixels
    pixels = data[:]

    # This array will be of 1D with length 784
    # The pixel intensity values are integers from 0 to 255
    pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype='uint8')

    # Reshape the array into 28 x 28 array (2-dimensional array)
    pixels = pixels.reshape((28, 28))
    i +=1
    # Plot
    plt.title('Label is {label}'.format(label=label))
    plt.imshow(pixels, cmap='gray')
    plt.savefig(str(i))'
```

With this I am unable to save each image.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly happens when you run the script? Is the apostrophe at the end of the last line intentional?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file should end with the extention you want,

```
plt.savefig(str(i)+".png")
```

or you need to specify the `format`:

```
plt.savefig(str(i), format="png")
```

One additional problem you may run into is that after a while your plotting slows down, because all images are placed on top of each other. To circumvent this, you may call `plt.close()` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the I had to use, 'plt.close()'. Actually, the code runs fine. I had saved a hundred images by hand without the loop, with the same name that the loop would give. And as it took so long to save the image, I thought the program was not running.

Comment: Sorry, the OP said 'I want to save each of these images without looking at them with imshow'. Does the solution work without first showing the image?

Comment: @StatsSorceress Yes, the function `imshow` creates the image. As long as you don't call `plt.show()` the figure is not shown. (As long as you're not using jupyter, but that would be a different question)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Can you explain how this would change if using Jupyte?

Comment: @MatthewArthur It would be same in Jupyter.